# Launch server and client simultaneously with ability to use breakpoints - using VS Code Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a `Create-React-App` where I have configured the `.launch.json` file to have 2 configurations

1. Launch via NPM - to launch server via `npm start`
2. Launch Chrome - to open the client and debug my web-app with breakpoints

Right now I can only choose one option from the drop-down. So i'm manually running `npm start` in the terminal and then using the debugger to `Launch Chrome` which enables breakpoints

**But I would like to know how to launch these 2 configs simultaneously using the VS Code debugger. Is it possible?**

Below is the config that I have in `launch.json`:

```json
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      // This doesn't stop at breakpoints
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "start"],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "type": "pwa-node"
    },

    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [compounds](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) in `launch.json` file to run 2 configs simultaneously.

so you need to add another array called `compounds` in launch.json after `configurations` like below

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "start"],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "type": "pwa-node"
    },

    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ],

  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Server + Browser",
      "configurations": ["Launch via NPM", "Launch Edge"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The compound - `Server + Browser` will be visible in the Run and Debug dropdown in VS Code

### TIP

You can also [set a delay for one of the configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55185885/6908282) by using `tasks.json`