# How can I easily run multiple launch config debug sessions with sequential startup instead of parallel startup?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, sveltekit

I finally have debugging working on both the client and server for SvelteKit in VS Code.  But I can't figure out how to get both configs to start up with one combined configuration or something similar.  I just want to run once in the debugger, it starts up the dev server, attaches to the node.js Vite process on the server side on the first config, then launches chrome and attaches the debugger on the second config.

I can do this manually by starting the server debug config, then select the "Launch Chrome" config, and both debuggers will be running and working, The compounds launch config is almost what I need, but they start in parallel.  This doesn't allow the server to start fast enough and chrome misses attaching to it. I tried different things with tasks, but I could never get the debugger to attach correctly.

Here are my two debug configs:

```
{
     "type": "node-terminal",
     "name": "Run Script: dev",
     "request": "launch",
     "command": "npm run devv",
     "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
{
     "name": "Launch Chrome",
     "request": "launch",
     "type": "chrome",
     "url": "http://localhost:5173",
     "port": 5173,
     "smartStep": true,
     "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**",
          "node_modules/**",
          "/**/*.js",
          "/**/*.css",
          "/*\\.js"
     ],
     "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chrome"
}
```

eg: I can't figure out how to setup one config, that runs the dev server config and then the launch chrome config sequentially instead of in parallel.

Comment: "_Also, how to skip all the internal and generated files?_" move this question to its own question post. In general, you should only to ask one question per question post.

Comment: it's not really necessary to show all those steps to understand your core question- which is how to easily run multiple launch configs in sequential order. You should remove an info which isn't necessary to understand and answer the question. If you want to share the info in those steps, then ask a dedicated question where you can post those steps as the answer to that question.

Comment: Ok, my bad.  I'll take them out. I thought they would be pertinent in the fact that someone might need to know how the configs are setup and why I can't get it working.  I also just thought it would be good for someone else in the future, it took me a long time of reading and combining different info scattered to actually get a decent debugging experience going, but I'll remove it. I see it's not the correct place for it.

Comment: thanks. as I said, you can write a question and answer it yourself if you want to share that info. that's even encouraged, as long as the question is a good question as defined in [ask], and the answer is a good answer as defined in [answer]. See also [/help/self-answer](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

There's such a thing as [Compound launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) to specify multiple launch configurations to launch in parallel, but unfortunately for you, it doesn't support running each launch config in sequential order, which is a bit of a shame, since tasks [have a compounding feature that allows for specifying that the tasks should run sequentially](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks).

See this feature-request issue ticket in the VS Code GitHub repo: [Run multiple launch.json test configurations in sequence #71885](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71885). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues compound launch config order sequence`".

Comment: I was trying to do the opposite though.  Not in parallel, but consecutively.  When they start at the same time, the Launch Chrome config starts too early before the dev server.  So it can't attach to it when it tries because it hasn't started yet.  I'd like to wait till the first config is started, then start the second.

Comment: I appreciate the answer a lot.  I can't believe it's not a feature already or something more people would want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this in another post.  The gist is to create a task that just waits x amount of seconds, and use that as your prelaunchtask for the Launch Chrome config.  Then create a compound debug config combining the client/server and it doesn't matter if they are then started in parallel.  The Launch Chrome config waits, then starts and gives the server enough to time to start.

I got the answer from this extremely helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55185885/5798864).

Comment: interesting. more like a hack/workaround. If the server takes longer than expected, it will fail, and you may find yourself wasting time waiting for a server that has already started. I was considering closing as a dup, but these are different questions- this one about sequential/dependent startup, and the other about a time delay. although now with more thought, I'm not sure how VS Code would even know when a launch config is "ready" for the next one to launch.